# Avoid href on click to open browser

Tags: javascript, html, href

I have this href link in a control that calls a javascript and pass the variable to it:

```
<a href="<%#XPath("link").ToString()%>" onclick="return getLink(this)">Link</a>
```

I need to stop it opening the browser. How can I do that?

Comment: What do you mean, stop it from refreshing the page? Or opening up a new one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`event.preventDefault();` will prevent the default behaviour of the click on the element.

So:

```
<a href="<%#XPath("link").ToString()%>" onclick="event.preventDefault(); return getLink(this)">Link</a>
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/AbwUW/

Comment: This, or do an event.preventDefault() on the inline JS

Comment: @FeliceM You are welcome! Glad to be of help to you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to prevent default browser behavior - just return false at onclick

```
<a href="<%#XPath("link").ToString()%>" onclick="getLink(this); return false;">Link</a>
```

or make function getLink to return false

[Examples](http://jsbin.com/rosegace/1/)

Comment: tried this already, does not work. It is still opening the browser

Comment: what browser ? Did you check link ( on jsbin ) ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="return getLink(this)">Link</a>`